# Jcycle2 progressive loading and Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, jcycle

I'm trying to get the Jcycle2's progressive loading script to work with my ACF fields. 
Problem is, the progressive loading script is with JSON, and i dont know how to implement my php into that.

From the Jcycle2 website:

```html
<div class="cycle-slideshow auto" 
    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    data-cycle-caption=".caption1"
    data-cycle-caption-template="{{slideNum}} / 9"
    data-cycle-loader=true
    data-cycle-progressive="#images"
    >
    <!-- only one image declared in markup -->
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">

    <!-- 
        JSON array of slides to be loaded progressively,
        nested inside a script block.  The script block does not need
        to be inslide the slideshow container, it can be anywhere on the
        page.  Note the type on the script tag.
    -->
    <script id="images" type="text/cycle">
[
    "<img src='http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg'>",
    "<img src='http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg'>",
    ...
    "<img src='http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg'>"
]
</script>
</div>
```

What I would ideally want is that the `<script>` part becomes a list of my images from my ACF repeater. Is this something possible?